# "In next section" or "in the next section"

Tags: definite-article

I wrote:

> In next section, we review LTAG and its essential features.

However as I searched google, I saw both "In next section" and "In the next section".

While the next section is known for the reader, I don't know if I should use "the" or it can be ommitted? if yes, why?

Comment: You need **the** there.  **Next** and **former** and **previous** etc are not determiners.   Ngram is not perfect, but use it, not Google, when searching for things of this nature. With Google you have no way to know whether the author is a native speaker; at least with Ngram they are published works that most likely have been edited. https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=in+next+section%2Cin+the+next+section&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cin%20next%20section%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cin%20the%20next%20section%3B%2Cc0

Comment: @TRomano thank you, wish I could, Google has banned that service from my country!

Comment: You should add some search examples/links for "In next section". There might be some contextual reason why it works. Or possibly just wrong.

Comment: Some countries have centralized firewalls that filter internet content. Are you certain it is Google?

Comment: @TRomano Yes, my own country filters many websites, but in the case of Google it is the google's restriction with the google logo telling "*Your client does not have permission to get URL /ngrams/graph from this server. That’s all we know.*". It could be some laws forced by the US Gov. However, through some software I can get around both internal and external filters.

Comment: @Ahmad - The US doesn't generally have laws blocking foreign users from viewing certain types of web content.  If I had to guess, the copyright status of the word corpora might be under dispute in some places.

Comment: @Ahmad You need to be certain of this: **There are _no laws_ in the U.S., or "forced by the U.S." which prohibit _anyone, anywhere on Earth_ from viewing any web content.** However, there are many _other_ nations which do prevent their citizens from reading what they please. Google often abides by these laws because it is in their economic interest to kowtow.

Comment: @Ahmad When you see the message _"Your client does not have permission to get URL /ngrams/graph from this server. That’s all we know,"_ it means that Google is prevented by a _local_ rule at the _network edge_ from processing ngram queries which originate from your IP address. So, in this case Google does not assist in the repression; instead it is your nation's own snoop utilities which prevent you from making your own choice about what to read.

Comment: @P.E.Dant In this case, certainly no!, the google don't obey such a prevention issued by Iran gov. and my gov. also doesn't prevent such a useful and unpolitical service like *ngrams*. There are other services from google (like Analytic) and many other Us companies which are inaccessible for Iranians (**Oracle** shows **nothing** from their website) , I should say about a controversial decision by Yahoo! once to ban Iranian from Yahoo Email Account! However I think now it resolved. One can count many others.

Comment: @Ahmad It is quite possible that the word or phrase you entered in the ngram invoked a content filter imposed by the government of Iran. This would not be surprising, sadly. See this [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_censorship_in_Iran).

Comment: @P.E.Dant I receive error 403, I am not sure the cause of this error, because it can be for other reasons like untrusted networks... But, I am sure some services from google is banned for Iranians,,https://support.google.com/a/answer/2891389?hl=en or http://www.niacinsight.com/2016/05/27/why-is-google-analytics-blocking-iranians-thank-the-embargo/

Comment: @P.E.Dant or https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/sanctions-lifted-yet-iranian-users-couldnt-access-some-naeimabadi

Comment: @Ahmad A 403 wrror should mean "Access denied for policy reasons" or similar.  In other words: "You can't see this and we won't tell you why." This does appear to be an internal censorship issue. You have my deep sympathy.

Comment: @P.E.Dant Thank you, I also wish a day barriers eliminate for all people of the world.

Answer (score 2):

It should definitely be *in* **the** *next section*.

You will find many incorrect translations on the internet because there are languages that do not have the 'the' article there (or article and preposition are combined like in the German *im nächster ....*), and people translate that from their language to English too literally.